# Метод Крамера с++

Tags: c++

Здраствуйте, скажите, пожалуйста, почему Type name expected?

```
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<vcl.h>
#include<iostream.h>
#pragma hdrstop

float opr(float arr[][3]) {
        float opr, p1, p2, p3;
        p1=arr[0][0]*arr[1][1]*arr[2][2]+arr[2][0]*arr[0][1]*arr[1][2];
        p2=arr[0][2]*arr[1][0]*arr[2][1]-arr[2][0]*arr[1][1]*arr[0][2];
        p3=arr[0][0]*arr[2][1]*arr[1][2]-arr[1][0]*arr[0][1]*arr[2][2];
        opr=p1+p2+p3;
        return opr;
}
#pragma hdrstop
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
        float A[3][3]={{2.84,-4.3,2.14},
                       {-4.32,1.52,-4.36},
                       {2.14,-4.36,2.46}};
        };
        int i,j;
        float B[3]={4.96,2.3,1.76}, X, x1, x2, x3, X1_o;
        float X1m[3][3], X2m[3][3], X2_o, X3m[3][3], X3_o;
        X=opr(A);//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////здесь

        printf("\nMatricya: \n\n");
        for(i=0;i<3;i++){
                for(j=0;j<3;j++){
                        printf("%2.2f\t",A[i][j]);
                }
                printf("=%2.2f",B[i]);
                printf("\n");
        }
        for(i=0;i<3;i++)
                for(j=0;j<3;j++){
                       X1m[i][j]=A[i][j];
                       X2m[i][j]=A[i][j];
                       X3m[i][j]=A[i][j];
                }
        }
        for(i=0;i<3;i++)
                X1m[i][0]=B[i];
                X2m[i][1]=B[i];
                X3m[i][2]=B[i];
        }
        X1_o=opr(X1m);
        X2_o=opr(X2m);
        X3_o=opr(X3m);
        x1=X1_o/X;
        x2=X2_o/X;
        x3=X3_o/X;
        printf("\n---\nx1 = %f\nx2 = %f\nx3 = %f", x1, x2, x3);
        getch();
        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Внимательней, вы два раза закрыли массив:

```
float A[3][3]={{2.84,-4.3,2.14},
                       {-4.32,1.52,-4.36},
                       {2.14,-4.36,2.46}};
        };
```

Форматирование позволяет такое замечать сразу, как и многие другие потенциальные ляпы:

```
float A[3][3] = 
{
  { 2.84, -4.3,   2.14 },
  {-4.32,  1.52, -4.36 },
  { 2.14, -4.36,  2.46 }
};
}; // ???
```

Comment: Понял, вопрос был глупый. Спешу очень. Спасибо)

Comment: а в почему в рядке

Comment: for(i=0;i<3;i++){/////////////////////declaration terminated incorrectly
                X1m[i][0]=B[i];
                X2m[i][1]=B[i];
                X3m[i][2]=B[i];
        }
        X1_o=opr(X1m);
        X2_o=opr(X2m);
        X3_o=opr(X3m);
        x1=X1_o/X;
        x2=X2_o/X;

Comment: сначала пропустил скобку, доставил, но все равно ошибка

Comment: У вас скобок для `for` в двух местах не хватает. Всё-таки начните с форматирования, когда открывающая скобка находится точно над закрывающей. Сразу видно будет. Любая IDE это умеет.

Comment: спасибо, учту Ваш совет